# Merge of key-value stores

Tags: merge, diff

Is there some merge strategy or program which is aware of key-value stores, in the sense that the sequence of the lines does not matter*? For a real example, [jEdit](http://www.jedit.org/) does not keep the order of options, so there are hundreds of lines which are shuffled around. It would be nice to diff/merge these without having to sort the file first, for example to see how *values are changed* and *keys are added/removed* by configuration modifications while the program is running.

* I know it matters for some file types, like shell scripts where you can have references to other keys. These of course should be merged normally.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if the stores are unsorted then comparing them will cost `O(n*m)` time, if you first sort them you can run it in `O(n log n + m log m)` for the sort plus `O(n+m)` for the check, so if the stores are reasonably large then sorting is way faster